# HTTP Header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJK........7rkFMLiRXERZwkT0' is not allowed in responses

Tags: scala, playframework

After migrating to **Play 2.6** I get this log warning:

```
HTTP Header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1.....
JYsNqGyU2iHU1sh3A6Gtk_4jY' is not allowed in responses,
you can turn off this warning by setting `play.server.akka.illegal-response-header-value-processing-mode = ignore`
```

According to this discussion: [playframework/issues/7549](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7549) this should be resolved.

Also adding the proposed `play.server.akka.illegal-response-header-value-processing-mode = ignore` did not get rid of this message.

The Header is added by `"com.pauldijou" %% "jwt-play" % "0.16.0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's closed as referrenced to akka, and fixed in akka, but akka HTTP with that fix still not merged into the play.

So
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7549

Fixed as referenced to https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1550

That is fixed by pool request https://github.com/akka/akka-http/pull/1577

The fix is introducing the `akka.http.parsing.modeled-header-parsing` settings, that handles the headers parsing in the akka. It looks like it needs to be set to `off` to fix your issue:

```
akka.http.parsing.modeled-header-parsing = off
```

[image]

The akka-http setting right after the fix commit:
https://github.com/jrudolph/akka-http/blob/f0aca4d7b9e09c63ebc7fc1ae0174b4102f6958d/akka-http-core/src/main/resources/reference.conf

**But**, this fix in akka still not integrated into play:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7737
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/8296

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the warning without adding
`akka.http.parsing.modeled-header-parsing = off`:

Rename the request attribute `Authorization` to a name that is not an `official` request attribute, for example `MyAuthorization`.

In my case I needed to add this property:

`play.http.session.jwtName="MyAuthorization"`